# tomcat behind 2 apache http servers

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-jk, ajp

I have this architecture:

```
            http                   Ajp
[Apache A] -------> [Apache B] ----------> [Tomcat]
```

there is a way to configure [Apache B] to forward an ajp request in order to achive this:

```
             Ajp                  Ajp
[Apache A] -------> [Apache B] ----------> [Tomcat]
```

???

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need mod_proxy_ajp, which adds ajp support to mod_proxy.

Comment: I know how to forward an http request on the ajp channel. But how configure [Apache B] to catch the ajp incoming connection? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a reverse proxy on Apache A, so that all requests for your app go to Apache B with a config like:

```
ProxyPass /myapp http://apacheb.domain.com/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://apacheb.domiain.com/myapp
```

Then, using [ModJK](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html) on Apache B, you set up a workers.properties file to define your tomcat servers and any load-balancing and connection parameters.  In your vhost block, you set JKmounts to the tomcat server.  So, if you have www.domain.com/myapp as a tomcat application, you would do

```
jkmount /myapp/* worker1
```

Where worker1 would be defined in the workers.properties file like:

```
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=tomcat_host_name
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
```

So the request will come in to apache A, which will get proxied to B and then mod_jk'ed over to the tomcat server.

Comment: i'm forced to do this. there's a firewall between the two apache and the only connection that I can establish is to the second apache, and obviously i cannot change the firewall configuration

Comment: Ok.  In that case, I think the first scenario is going to be the best bet.  Set up a mod_proxy from A->B, so that everything gets proxied to Apache B.  So all A is doing is acting as a gateway for everything to B.  Then setup ModJK (or mod_proxy_ajp if you prefer) from Apache B to the tomcat server.  Since everything is effectively proxied twice, there were most certainly be some performance impact with this.

Comment: I have modified my answer to reflect what I was talking about in my last comment.  I have not tried a setup like this, but I think this will work.